# Media upload default title from file name

Tags: filters, wp-admin, media-library

I'm on a roll today with the questions. Is this easy?
Again, I can't seem to find the right filter (nor previous question with a suitable answer).

So if you download an image say, from GettyImages, it might have some meta title and WP will snack that up for the title field, I do not want this kind of behavior as the files are named precisely for a reason. I'd like to either leave the title blank or more preferrably copy over the file name. I tried to hook up to the `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` but doesn't seem to do the trick.

Although even with the right filter, I'm not sure I'd know what to do to get the file name over.. Any help appreciated.

Thanks again fellows.

Comment: There are plugins that removes metadata and Exif from images. EWWW Image Optimizer, ImageMagick Engine and Exif-Remove-ImageMagick. You can find many other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Where in core ?

These parts [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/81d0434421e0d3d3fddfb853c0befae2a210f4fa/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L338-347) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/81d0434421e0d3d3fddfb853c0befae2a210f4fa/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L402-408), are responsible for overriding the image title with meta data:

```
// ... cut ...
// Use image exif/iptc data for title and caption defaults if possible.
} elseif ( 
          0 === strpos( $type, 'image/' ) 
       && $image_meta = @wp_read_image_metadata( $file ) 
  ) {
    if ( 
           trim( $image_meta['title'] ) 
        && ! is_numeric( sanitize_title( $image_meta['title'] ) ) 
    ) {
        $title = $image_meta['title'];
    }
    if ( trim( $image_meta['caption'] ) ) {
        $excerpt = $image_meta['caption'];
    }
}
// ... cut ...
```

### Possible workaround:

One can bypass this feature by overriding the meta title for `jpeg` and `tiff` images (PHP 5.4+):

```
/**
 * Override the meta title for jpeg/tiff images
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192779/26350
 */
add_filter( 'wp_read_image_metadata', function( $meta, $file, $sourceImageType )
{
    $image_types = [ IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM ];

    if( ! empty( $meta['title'] ) && in_array( $sourceImageType, $image_types ) )    
        $meta['title'] = ''; // <-- Edit this to your needs!

    return $meta;

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: The answer for me except ['title'] = $file puts the entire path in the title. How do I just grab the file name?

Comment: See eg https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php